# How to get list of only already created groups?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I know how to get list of tabs consists in certain group:

```
var possible_colors = ['grey', 'blue', 'red', 'yellow', 'green', 'pink', 'purple', 'cyan', 'orange']

chrome.tabGroups.query({ color: possible_colors[1] }, function (group) {
    chrome.tabs.query({ groupId: group[0].id }, function (tabs) {
        console.log(tabs)
    })
})
```

But I want to get list of only created/exists groups in current chrome window. Maybe it's somehow possible by Chrome Extensions API and without loop through all `possible_colors` to check like this:

```
for (var color of possible_colors) {
    chrome.tabGroups.query({ color: color }, function (group) {
        if (!group.length) return

        chrome.tabs.query({ groupId: group[0].id }, function (tabs) {
            console.log(tabs)
        })
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet, found how do get all existing groups for current Chrome window:

```
chrome.windows.getCurrent(function (win) {
    chrome.tabGroups.query({ windowId: win.id }, function (groups) {
         console.log(groups) // output is array of all groups
    })
})
```